# converting number bases to string using a recursive function javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, radix

I'm trying to write a recursive function that takes two parameters - an integer input, n, and an integer base, m - and returns a string representation of the number in Base m. I'm stuck can someone help?

```
const toStr = (n, base) => {
   //when no remainder return 1
  if(n % base === 0) return 1;
  if(n % base >= 1){
   return toStr(Math.floor(n/base))+(n % base);
  }
  return " ";
}


toStr(199, 10) //'199'
toStr(14, 8)//'16'
toStr(30, 2)//'11110'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include `base` in recursive call

And to reduce complexity, the base case of this recursion call is to check whether n is zero, then return empty string to concat with the returned from upper stack call

```js
const toStr = (n, base) => {
  //when no remainder return 1
  if (!n) {
    return "";
  }
  return toStr(Math.floor(n / base), base) + (n % base);
};

console.log(toStr(199, 10)); //'199'
console.log(toStr(14, 8)); //'16'
console.log(toStr(30, 2)); //'11110'
```

Comment: For a thorough answer, how would this work for base greater than 10? Maybe mention that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some general advice:- Always figure out the logic behind the problem/solution before you worry about the actual code for the program.

A little more specific now:-
Your first line of code returns 1 when reminder is 0, why is that? When the reminder is 0, it means that the dividend is a multiple of the divisor.

Here is (hopefully) an understandable algorithm explanation (you can always search online for the perfect explanations and the most performant one):

- Starting with the right most digit of the input `n`, your reminder (say `r`, we will come to representation of `r` soon) at every step would be the current digit of the output starting from the right.
- Once you have the current digit, you subtract `r` from `n` and then divide `r` by `base` to get the quotient (say `q`).
- This quotient now becomes `n` for the next digit from the right. Hence go back to the first step treating this `q` as `n` to get the next digit and so on till `q` < `base`.
- The accepted string representation of `r` at any digit is `0-9` when `0 <= r <= 9` and `a-z` when `10 <= r <= 35`. Hence, something like this would work: `r > 9 ? String.fromCharCode(87 + r) : String.fromCharCode(48 + r)` since ascii value of `a` is `97` and `0` is `48`.

Here is a code fragment that should hopefully work:

```
function toStr(n, base) {
    if(n == 0) return ""; 
    let r = n % base; // r is the reminder
    return toStr((n - r) / base, base) // ((n - r) / base) is the quotient to consider as n for the rest of the conversion after extracting the right most digit
        + (r > 9 ? String.fromCharCode(87 + r) : String.fromCharCode(48 + r)); // concatenate the right most digit to the rest of the conversion
}
```